# How to output multiple graphs using sns.distplot()

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have 3 lists of data.
If I do:

```
sns.distplot(data1)
sns.distplot(data2)
sns.distplot(data3)
```

I'm going to get a single graph with 3 different distributions on the same graph.
I'd like to output 3 individual distributions. How do I do this without using subplots? I find that subplots are too cramped and small.

Thanks

Comment: `plt.figure()` creates a new figure.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `figsize` accordingly when creating subplots:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data1, data2, data3 = [np.random.normal(size=[100]) for _ in range(3)]

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 4))
sns.distplot(data1, ax=ax1)
sns.distplot(data2, ax=ax2)
sns.distplot(data3, ax=ax3)
```

[Here's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL3wd.png)